# switching selections between two select menus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build some kind of currency converter and I have two select menus with the list of currencies.
I want to create a button that when clicked, it will switch the selection between the "from" select menu and the "to" select menu.
how do I implement it using the select menus I already have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you'r looking for a swap behavior.

http://jsfiddle.net/brentmn/D55Dm/

```
$(function(){
    var $sel1 = $('#currency1');
    var $sel2 = $('#currency2');

    $('input[type=button]').click(function(){
        var val1 = $sel1.val();
        var val2 = $sel2.val();
        $sel2.val(val1);
        $sel1.val(val2);  
        //jqueryui
        //$sel2.val(val1).trigger('change');
        //$sel1.val(val2).trigger('change');               
    });
});
```

Comment: will it work if I've used jquery ui to design the select menus ? since it doesn't work for me

Comment: @Alon, see the commented changes I made in the example; this might work.  I can't test unless you provide me with the actual jquery-ui script that you're using for the menus.  Post a link to the script.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$("#button").on("click", function() {
    var from = $("#from").val();
    var to = $("#to").val();
    $("#from").val(to);
    $("#to").val(from);
});
```

I'd really do it with less code than that, but have done it like that for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've understood you correctly, you want a button that will swap the values of two `select` elements. If that's right, try something along these lines:

```
$("#someButton").click(function() {
    var elemTo = $("#to"),
        elemFrom = $("#from"),
        toVal = elemTo.val();
    elemTo.val(elemFrom.val());
    elemFrom.val(toVal);
});
```

It simply gets references to the two `select` elements (assumed here to be `#to` and `#from`), gets the value of one of them, replaces the value of that one with the value of the other, and then replaces the value of the second with the stored value from the first.

*Note that this assumes both `select` elements have the same `option` values. If an `option` is present in one `select` but not the other, it would not work.*

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/g7J8N/1/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm using jquery ui, ui selectmenu for my selects and your example doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you dbl click on one item in 'From' section , it will get selected be appended to the 'To' section.

```
$("#selectFrom").dblclick(function(){
    $selectTo.append($selectFrom.children(":selected"));
});
```

Which all functionalities you want??